# Simple Countdown Timer with image background

Tags: javascript, css

I am having trouble finding a proper CSS/script for a simple countdown timer,
The requirement is below

- Days countdown only (no need to be have hrs, mins and secs)
- be able to use my own image as background

I have tried a lot of online search however no luck
any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? So your efforts. Describe your specific problem. So that people here can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as simple as you can get. Pure Javascript solution.

http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/PNdKBZ

```
today = new Date();
target = new Date("April 30, 2016");
msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
timeLeft = (target.getTime() - today.getTime());
e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
document.write("There are only<br> <strong>" + daysLeft + " days </strong><br> until April 30th 2016<P>");
```

Note, once it gets within the last 24 hours, it will display 0 days left.

Comment: Thank you! How to do I add a background image for this countdown?

Comment: Ok so now you can see how to add the countdown all you need to do is add the html and css to the page so that you can style it accordingly. To make the above JS play nicely i've updated the method used to output the countdown to the screen. http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/PNdKBZ

Comment: Thanks, I have applied the code to my page however the java does seem to be working, I have doubled check the html, css and JS. Could I have done something wrong?

Comment: I have use <script type="text/javascript"</script> for the JS, but it doesn't seem working, the image is appearing fine though.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Day Countdown</title>
    <style>/* css goes here */</style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="countdown-wrap">
  <div id="countdown"></div>
  </div>
  <script><!--// script goes here --></script>
</body>
</html>